# Header files for c code compiled by arm-gcc compiler

Tags: android, c, gcc, header-files, cross-compiling

I used string.h header file in a c code that is to be compiled using arm-gcc compiler and the executable generated is to be executed on an android device.
When I pushed my executable on to the device and executed it, it presented me with linkage error.
How can I use functions from string.h on such a device?
Are these header files hardware specific?

Comment: i used strstr() and the error was
cannot link strstr

Comment: also functions from stdio.h and stdlib.h can be used easily and perfectly

Comment: Are you using the NDK?  Which compiler?

Comment: [`strstr()`](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/string/strstr.c) exists in *bionic*.  You have a tool/build issue.

Comment: I am using SDK for this project

Answer (score 1):

The ARM EABI states that the header files for the ANSI C-library should be provided by the compiler independent from where  the library comes. If you are cross-compiling you do however have to make sure you use the `string.h` coming with the compiler and not from the native system. What linkage error did you get?

It sounds like `strstr` is missing in the `libc`, which sounds weird and I don't have an explanation for it. If you have access to the library on the device, then I would check with for example `objdump -t` if it defines `strstr`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use functions from string.h on such a device?

It's worked for me in the past.

> Are these header files hardware specific?

With the NDK tools, they are architecture and platform (e.g., Android 8, Android 14, et al.) specific.

Unless there's a serious bug in the NDK (which seems unlikely), I think you might want to check your build again.

Comment: i tried to rebuild the code and strstr did not give any error but this was the error : `cannot locate '__strlen_chk'... CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE`

Comment: I am using SDK for the development

Comment: AFAIK, the Android SDK does not have a C compiler bundled with it.  That's what the Android NDK is for.